# How to read multiple doubles that are in a string, separated by spaces, in C++?

Tags: c++, string, double

I need to read in a string such as:

```html
string str = "3 - 90.2 85.54 93.0";
```

...in this format. The first number shows the number of doubles, followed by a " = " and then that many doubles separated by spaces).
I know how to read the first number as an int to find the number of doubles. However, what is troubling me is the reading of the doubles. I tried using the stod function.

```html
string str = "90.2 85.54 93.0";
size_t sz;

double x = stod(str,&sz);
double y = stod(str.substr(sz));
double z = stod(str.substr(sz));
```

However, this can only read up to 2 doubles since str.substr(sz) will read to the end of the string, and the doubles can be with different decimals (it could be 89.54 or 89 or 89.6), so I can't use substr since that requires me to know how many characters to read from the starting index.

Is there any way to read in these unknown count of doubles with unknown number of decimal numerals? Is there another method such as substr to read up to a specific index or character? 
I just want them to be able to be read one by run. I can later store it into a double array (which I know how to do).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can use stringstream

```
string str = "3 - 90.2 85.54 93.0";
stringstream ss(str);
int num;   ss >> num; //read 3
char c;    ss >> c;    // read "-"
double d1; ss >> d1;   // read 1
double d2; ss >> d2;   // read 2
double d2; ss >> d2;   // read 3
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `istream_iterator`s.

```
std::vector<double> xyzzy{std::istream_iterator<double>{std::istringstream{str}}, std::istream_iterator{}};
```

Note that streams don't have move constructors in GCC so you'll need to declare your `istringstream` and pass a reference to it if you're using GCC, like this:

```
std::istringstream temp{str};
std::vector<double> xyzzy{std::istream_iterator<double>{temp}, std::istream_iterator{}};
```

Answer (score 0):

The function strtok() is pretty useful for parsing things out of larger strings.  Once you have pch pointing to each double then convert it using a call to atof().

```
  char str[] ="- This, a sample string.";
  char * pch;
  printf ("Splitting string \"%s\" into tokens:\n",str);
  pch = strtok (str," ");
  while (pch != NULL)
  {
     printf ("%s\n",pch);
     pch = strtok (NULL, " ");
  }
```

Comment: That is the C way of doibg it, not the C++ way.

Comment: But as you can see, there are numerous ways to accomplish the same thing.  Preference, code clarity/familiarity usually determine which one you ultimately go with.

Answer (score 0):

You can just repeat the code:

```
double x = stod(str, &sz);
str = str.substr(sz);
double y = stod(str, &sz);
str = str.substr(sz);
double z = stod(str, &sz);
str = str.substr(sz);
double x1 = stod(str, &sz);
```

See the documentation:

```
double stod(const string &  str, size_t * idx = 0);
```

- `str`: String object with the representation of a floating-point
  number.
- `idx`: Pointer to an object of type size_t, whose value is set by the
  function to position of the next character in `str` after the
  numerical value. This parameter can also be a null pointer, in which
  case it is not used.

Answer (score -1):

You can even split a string using the while loop, theres no limit of floats in a string, as this will end as the string ends, do this:

```
int i=0, p=0;
float fdigit=0;
char string[]="9.0 5.4 2.6", floats[10];
while (floats[i]!='\0')
{
while (floats[i]!=' ')
{
floats[p]=floats[i];
p++;
i++;
floats[p]='\0';
fdigit=atof(floats);
cout<<fdigit<<"\n";
}
if (floats[i]==' ')
i++;
}
```

Also do not forget to put stdlib.h, as atof is in the stdlib.h library, atof() simply converts string floats to type floats, Hope this helps u, if you have any questions then ask me, don't hesitate to ask me, bro...

EDIT: Also do not forget to +1 vote to my question if this helps u...

Answer (score -1):

```
std::string str = "3 - 90.2 85.54 93.0";
std::stringstream ss(str);
int num;   ss >> num;
char c;    ss >> c;
std::vector arr;
arr.reserve(num);
for (int i = 0; i < num; ++i)
{
    double d; ss >> d;
    arr.push_back(d);
}
```